# videojs-youtube, start and end parameters don't work if both are set

Tags: youtube, video.js

I am using the [videojs-youtube](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-youtube) plugin to play YouTube videos using videojs.

If I set the start youtube parameter like this, it will work perfectly and the video will start at the fifth second.

```
{ "techOrder": ["youtube"], "sources": [{ "type": "video/youtube", "src": "video_url_here"}], "youtube": {"start": 5}}
```

If I set the end youtube parameter like this, it will work perfectly and the video will end in the second 10.

```
{ "techOrder": ["youtube"], "sources": [{ "type": "video/youtube", "src": "video_url_here"}], "youtube": {"end": 10}}
```

However, when I set both, the video won't end at the specified end parameter.

```
{ "techOrder": ["youtube"], "sources": [{ "type": "video/youtube", "src": "video_url_here"}], "youtube": {"start": 5, "end": 10}}
```

Am I missing something?

The very same video will start and stop at the specified time if played on YouTube directly, and if I inspect the network, I can see that the request is using the right parameters.

```
Referer: https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxx?controls=0&end=10&start=5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a typo on the plugin, I submitted a [PR](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-youtube/pull/521/files) and fixed it. Works as intended now.